# How to perform multiple selections in a Qlikview Straight Table?

Tags: qlikview

How would I go about making multiple selections in a QlikView straight table?

For example, how would I select the 1st and 5th rows at the same time?

Comment: Can't you just CTRL+Click?

Answer (score 3):

There is a section about multiple selections in the [QlikView 11 - Reference Manual](http://community.qlikview.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/4549-1-69195/QlikView%20Reference%20Manual.pdf) :

> > > ## 14.5 Multiple Selection Within a Field
> > >
> > > Multiple selections within a field (from one lisstrong textt box) can be made in a number of ways:
> > >
> > > - Position the cursor in the list box, then drag it over a number of field values while pressing the
> > >         mouse button.
> > > - Click the first field value to be selected, then CTRL-click each additional selection.
> > > - Click the top item to be selected, then SHIFT-click the bottom item to be selected. This way all the
> > >         items in between will be selected. However, if the sort mechanism is on, the first selection may cause
> > >         the order to change, which makes it difficult to make a correct second selection.
> > > - Confirm a text search (see below) by hitting the ENTER key. This will result in all matching field
> > >         values being selected. By keeping the CTRL key depressed while pressing ENTER the selections
> > >         from the text search will be added to previous selections.
> > >
> > > To deselect a previously made additional selection, CTRL-click it.
> > >       If a multiple selection is made in one list box, and make a new selection from the available optional values
> > >       in another list box, some of the selected values in the first list box may get excluded. However, when the
> > >       selection in the second list box is canceled, the previous selections will, by default, be recovered.
> > >       A multiple selection can be interpreted in two different ways, either as a logical or or as a logical and.
> > >       Default is logical or, i.e. QlikView will find a solution that is associated to one or more of the selected field
> > >       values.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

For straight tables, you can only select items next to each other. Ctrl-Select only works for listboxes